# how to convert string to identity in java

Tags: java

I have folowing class:

```
public class Person {
     private Identity<Person> personId;

     public void setPersonId(Identity<Person> personId){
           this.personId = personId;
     }
}
```

now i want to assign some String to be persons identity:

```
 Person p = new Person();
 p.setPersonId("ABC123");
```

This is my Identity class:

```
public class Identity<T> implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@NotNull
String str;

String getStr() {
    return str;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Identity) {
        return str.equals(((Identity<?>) obj).getStr());
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return str.hashCode();
}

public Identity() {
}

Identity(String str) {
    this.str = str;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return str;
}

public static final <T> Identity<T> getIdentity() {
    return new Identity<T>(RandomStringUtils.random(32, true, true));
}
```

}

how can i conver `"ABC123"` to `Identity<Person>` so `ABC123` would be accpeted by `setPersonId()`?

//random text to meet post requirements
//Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt,

Comment: Where is the Identity<T> class from?

Comment: What is `Identity`? A class you have written? Where's the code?

Comment: You might have to do the conversion yourself, e.g. depending on what `Identity` looks like it _could_ be as simple as `p.setPersonId(new Identity<Person>("ABC123"));`. The problem is that we're missing a lot of information as already stated by the others so we can't help you much so far.

Comment: added Identity class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need this class `Indentity`?

If not you can remove `private Identity<Person> personId;` of the `Person` and add `private String personId;`

But if you need this class, just call `p.setPersonId(new Identity<Person>("ABC123"));` or change

`public void setPersonId(Identity<Person> personId){
  this.personId = personId;
}`

to

`public void setPersonId(String personId){
  this.personId = new Identity<Person>(personId);
}`

Comment: its one of soultions and its correct but i figured that setting parametrized contructor to public does everything i need